# Action Bar Style causes Action Bar to disappear

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm trying to theme my Action Bar. When I apply my theme, the preview (in Android Studio) renders it correctly, but at runtime on a device the Action Bar is completely missing.

My values/styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_gray</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GreenActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>

    <style name="GreenActionBarBase">
        <item name="android:background">#00c341</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GreenActionBar" parent="GreenActionBarBase"/>    

</resources>
```

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Runtime:

[image: Runtime]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_gray</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/GreenActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>

    <style name="GreenActionBarBase" parent="@style/Widget.THE_STYLE_YOU_WANT">
        <item name="android:background">#00c341</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GreenActionBar" parent="GreenActionBarBase"/>    

</resources>
```

Check the answer. I think you need to have a parent for the `GreenActionBarBase`.

Comment: Yup, that is in fact what I overlooked. Thanks. For any future googlers, I went with Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid as the parent.